# terragrunt apply from root folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terragrunt

I need to work with terraform and terragrunt. There would be like 15 20 resources/services of AWS I need to deploy using IAC, while working on terragrunt what I found is if one of the layer needs to be applied, I need to go into that particular directory and run `terragrunt plan/apply`.

I was thinking if there is possible way to do the terragrunt apply just by sitting on the root folder. My folder structure now:

```
Root folder: terraform/
/layers/
          /iam-policies/main.tf
          /sagemaker/main.tf
```

Then for terragrunt similarly as layers(tf) environments(terragrunt/hcl) is also
in the terraform folder:

```
/environments/
        /iam-policies/terragrunt.hcl
       /sagemaker/terragrunt.hcl
```

Is there a way to apply `iam-policies` or `sagemaker` layer from the root folder i.e `terraform`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `terragrunt-include-dir` flag for this.

```bash
terragrunt plan-all --terragrunt-include-dir "iam-policies" --terragrund-include-dir "sagemaker"
```

There are other CLI [options](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/reference/cli-options/) that can be combined to achieve even finer selections in your directories.

Comment: There is `run-all` command now, since `plan-all` is being deprecated, but it seems to be working, thanks a lot.